# How to differentiate $b$ wrt $L_{b}?$

Tags: derivatives

I have the function $b = \varphi [\delta L_{b}^{\rho }+(1-\delta)g^{\rho }]^{\frac{1}{\rho }}$, where $\delta$,$\rho$,$\varphi$ are parameters.

How do I differentiate $b$ wrt $L_{b}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chain rule. Note that $\varphi, \delta$, $g$ and $\rho$ are all *constants*. $$\frac{{\rm d}b}{{\rm d}L_b} = \frac{\varphi}{\rho}[\delta L_b^\rho + (1-\delta)g^\rho]^{\frac{1}{\rho}-1} \cdot\delta\rho L_b^{\rho - 1}.$$
If $g$ is a function of $L_b$, one more chain rule comes into play, and the expression gets more complicated.